# Scrolling in all directions

Tags: android, custom-scrolling

I've been trying to implement an activity where I can scroll horizontally and vertically in all directions, I've tried out using gesturelistener and the "scrollby" method in View, however the screen is still static. I've also done a nested horizontal and vertical scroll in xml, however this only gives me scrolling to the right of the screen and bottom. It seems i cant move in the negative x direction.

Thanks.

Comment: try with https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager

Comment: Hello thanks however how do I implement this? there is no guide.

Answer (score 4):

- Customize ViewGroup
- Override OnTouchEvent
- Detect MotionEvents
- Track Finger Points
- Calculate Distance Moved
- Modify the X and Y of the canvas Content Rectangle.
- Finally in your layout add child views you want to scroll inside this ViewGroup

Source code: [https://gist.github.com/jayakrishnan-pm/ScrollingLayout.java](https://gist.github.com/jayakrishnan-pm/056d0ae6e4c29057e0a7744913481f29)